# Confirming a processed transaction

Tags: transactions, web3.js

Using `connection.confirmTransaction` getting the following error:

```
confirmTransaction error: Cannot assign to read only property '_nextClientSubscriptionId' of object '#<Connection>'
```

```
const blockdetails = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
tx.lastValidBlockHeight = blockdetails.lastValidBlockHeight;
tx.recentBlockhash = blockdetails.blockhash;
tx.feePayer = payer.publicKey;
const signedTx = await payer.signTransaction(tx);
const sendOptions: SendOptions = {
  maxRetries: 3,
  preflightCommitment: "processed",
  skipPreflight: true,
};
const txnSignature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
  signedTx.serialize(),
  sendOptions
;

const confirmStrategy: BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy = {
  signature: txnSignature,
  blockhash: blockdetails.blockhash,
  lastValidBlockHeight: blockdetails.lastValidBlockHeight,
};

const conf = await connection.confirmTransaction(
  confirmStrategy,
  "processed"
);
```

Comment: AFAIK confirmTransaction takes in the Tx Signature + commitment

Comment: @Pratik.js it's part of the `confirmStrategy` , the old `API` got `signature` and `commitment` only.

Comment: You're using Vue, aren't you @OhadDahan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly because you're using Vue, and:

- Your `Connection` object has undergone a [reactive/readonly](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html) transformation
- `Connection._nextClientSubscriptionId` is now a readonly [`ref`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)

Without seeing more of your code, my only suggestion is to figure out where this transformation is happening and either:

- stop it
- do it [shallowly](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#shallowreactive)
- mark the `Connection` object as [raw](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-advanced.html#markraw)

Comment: Actually using React, not sure what suddenly caused this change in my `Connection` object. But I worked around it by creating another `Connection` just for running `confirmTransaction`. Not the cleanest solution but works :)

Comment: Yeah, you need to take a look at where and how that original non-working `Connection` object is created and stored. I’m betting that there’s some code, somewhere, that’s modifying that instance.

Comment: OMG this happened to me on another repo now @steveluscher

Comment: Find the commonality!

Comment: Yeah, will see who's the culprit , seriously annoying issue.

Answer (score 3):

Posting an updated answer as I ran into the same problem, but not using Vue.

In my case we are using Recoil for state management, which transforms objects to `readonly`. Those using Recoil for state management should add the `dangerouslyAllowMutability: true` option to all `atoms` of the connection instance or `atoms` that have a nested connection instance (i.e. Anchor's `Program` class).